# Load github.io pages in own site

Tags: github, web, github-pages

I am just wondering if this can be made possible.

I have my own website with my domain. For eg. www.ownwebsite.com
I have an organization github site with the url username.github.io

My requirement is to load the contents of username.github.io site in my www.ownwebsite.com.

I want the URL to be ownwebsite.com

Comment: Github has docs regarding this: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be what GitHub describes in "[Setting up a custom domain with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages)"

Check also:

- "[How to point domain to site hosted on github pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376938/6309)"
- [how to take advantage of the CDN and DoS services provided by GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116100/6309)